# python argparse choices of string list accept unique partial list element

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to have the following rule

```
parser.add_argument('move', choices=['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
```

work also if you pass an unique subset of the characters (e.g. "k" or "oc" will be accepted as "rock" but not "r" since it's not unique).

My need is to be able to run the script with one or more arguments in the quickest possible way so avoiding writing the whole argument name when a subset would be sufficient for the script to understand the choice.

Is there a way to obtain this result still exploiting the handy choices list which integrates automatically in the help and in the errors handling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define a custom subclass of `list` that supports your definition of the `in` operator as "contains (part of) an element exactly once" like this:

```
class argList(list):
    def __contains__(self, other):
        "Check if <other> is a substring of exactly one element of <self>"
        num = 0
        for item in self:
            if other in item:
                num += 1
            if num > 1:
                return False
        return num==1
    def find(self, other):
        "Return the first element of <self> in which <other> can be found"
        for item in self:
            if other in item:
                return item
```

You could then use it to construct your argument list:

```
>>> l = argList(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])
>>> "rock" in l
True
>>> "ck" in l
True
>>> "r" in l
False
>>> "q" in l
False
```

and use it to construct your parser:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> l = argList(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])
>>> parser.add_argument("move", choices=l)
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='move', nargs=None, const=None, default=Non
e, type=None, choices=['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'], help=None, metavar=None)
```

Now it handles arguments correctly (although the error message is still a bit misleading):

```
>>> parser.parse_args(["rock"])
Namespace(move='rock')
>>> parser.parse_args(["r"])
usage: [-h] {rock,paper,scissors}
: error: argument move: invalid choice: 'r' (choose from 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
```

Note that the entered argument is retained which (of course) may be incomplete:

```
>>> parser.parse_args(["ck"])
Namespace(move='ck')
```

so you will have to find out which of your actual arguments was chosen:

```
>>> args = parser.parse_args(["ck"])
>>> l.find(vars(args)["move"])
'rock'
```

I haven't tested this much further - it might be that redefining in` has unexpected side effects in argument lists, and I guess it's questionable whether such program behavior violates the principle of least surprise - but it's a start.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly for me, yes the help invites to write the whole argument name but that is, even if not the only possibility, "a" working possibility so not error prone in my opinion. Many thanks.

Comment: `argparse` uses `choices` in only 2 ways, with contains `in`, and iteration `in` (to get a list to print).  So object that passes those 2 test should work fine.

Comment: You can also use the type= kwarg to get the intended command back out: `parser.add_argument("move", choices=l, type=l.find)`

Answer (score 3):

Tim's solution works very well but if you don't want to go to all the trouble of subclassing `list`, you can take advantage of the `type` argument and define your own type function:

```
choices = ['rock','paper','scissors']

def substring(s):
    options = [c for c in choices if s in c]
    if len(options) == 1:
        return options[0]
    return s

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("move", choices = choices, type = substring)
```

When you pass in the move argument the argument string will be passed to your substring function. Then, if the argument string is a substring of exactly one of the strings you've defined in the `choices` list, it will return that choice.  Otherwise, it will return your original argument string and argparse will probably then through an `invalid choice` error.